# htmlencode a variable inside a str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a variable and it works aka `{$record['click_here_to']}`, it is used inside a `str_replace` and that works.

```
$errorsAlerts = str_replace("dingdong bla", "{$record['click_here_to']}<br/>\n", $errorsAlerts);
```

My question is, I wanted to html encode it aka     `{htmlencode($record['click_here_to'])}`

But i get errors, I had thought adding the htmlencode on all my variables would help secure my site just a little bit more.

why wont this work : `{htmlencode($record['click_here_to'])}`

regards

Ionna

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: I'll guess that the error is about the quotes in the array because the function call breaks the complex variable syntax, `Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `htmlencode()`, i.e. write it outside of your `"`, as such :

```
$errorsAlerts = str_replace("dingdong bla", htmlencode($record['click_here_to']) . "<br/>\n", $errorsAlerts);
```

Comment: The `{}` are for complex variables. See `Complex (curly) syntax`, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. (and because of that the above edit should have been rejected, it is modifying the OPs code)

Comment: Didn't know about `Complex (curly) syntax`. Would `htmlencode({$record['click_here_to']})` work then ?

Comment: `htmlencode($record['click_here_to']) ."<br/>\n"` should do it, if it isn't being used for the complex, it will render the curlys. (assuming the OP defined `htmlencode`)